# Git: How to ignore/specify files for *checkout*

Tags: git

If I don't want .html files tracked I can add the pattern to .gitignore and they'll be ignored. I'd like to know how I can do the converse - at checkout, how could I ask git to only checkout certain types of files or not checkout certain types of files?

For example, if I didn't want html files I could write:

```
git checkout HEAD . --no .html
```

if that existed. Is there a way already built in, or do I just have to run something else post-checkout?

Comment: Readers that found this question while seeking a way to work with Git normally (e.g. checkouts, commits, merges, etc.) but with only a subset of the whole working tree present (i.e. another way to interpret “ignore/specify files for checkout”) should consider Git’s sparse checkout feature. It is documented in the [“Sparse Checkout” section](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) of the [*git read-tree* manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to package up files for deployment, you probably don't need - or want - the repo itself. This is exactly what [`git archive`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-archive.html) is for. A couple examples from the manpage (linked):

> `git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)`
>
> Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the current branch, and extract it in the /var/tmp/junk directory.
>
> `git archive --format=tar --prefix=git-1.4.0/ v1.4.0 | gzip > git-1.4.0.tar.gz`
>
> Create a compressed tarball for v1.4.0 release.

You ought to be able to get it to do exactly what you want, with the help of the `export-ignore` attribute:

> `export-ignore`
>
> Files and directories with the attribute export-ignore won’t be added to archive files. See [gitattributes(5)](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitattributes.html) for details.

For example, to exclude the directory `private` and the files `mine.txt` and `secret.c`, you could put in the file `.gitattributes`:

```
private/     export-ignore
secret.c     export-ignore
```

Just like gitignore files, you can put those anywhere in your repository, and they'll operate from that directory, but starting from the top level is a good bet.

Comment: this is a lot closer to what I'm looking for. At the very least I can pipe it through other commands so it's not an onerous process. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

### Git's Sparse-Checkout

If you only want to checkout a portion of your repository, you can use git's sparse-checkout option which has powerful include/exclude rules.

The following StackOverflow question has some helpful instructions:
***[GIT checkout except one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933702/git-checkout-except-one-folder)***

But as a summary:

1. Enable the `sparseCheckout` option:

   ```
   git config core.sparseCheckout true
   ```
2. Create the file called `.git/info/sparse-checkout` containing:

   ```
   /*
   !node_modules
   ```

   which effectively means include everything except the `node_modules` directory when checking out a repository into the working directory.

Comment: the config here is checked against all folders in the directory, so I believe it should be:

`!^node_modules`, else it will also ignore subdirectories named `node_modules`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want just a one-time change (or not consistent) or you just don't want to put files in `.gitignore` then do the below:

1. Stash specific files that you want to exclude from `checkout`

```sh
git stash push -m "files_to_ignore" my/path/of/the/file/file.txt
```

2. Do checkout as you expected before:

```sh
git checkout .
```

3. Extract stashed content:

```
git stash apply stash^{/files_to_ignore}
```

---

The complete solution using git aliases can look like this:

```
alias reset-non-dev='git stash push -m "ignore_files" MyRepo/file1.txt MyRepo/dir/file2.js MyRepo/dir/dir2/file3.cs PSOne/Startup/PSOne/Views/Login.xaml.cs ; git checkout . ; git stash apply stash^{/ignore_files} ;'
```

Later you can use this alias simply by putting its name in git bash and hitting enter.

One benefit here that I observed is that with this approach you can change the files or skip them whenever you really need it and not marked such files as always ignored.

Answer (score 2):

So I wanted to ship my code without the test files to the production server.

Easiest way for me was just to remove all the test files with: `rsync --exclude 'tests'` after unpacking the archive.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you use [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) as mentioned in [Simon East](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195835/simon-east)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814127), with rules like

```
/*
!^node_modules
```

But, starting with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), you can validate those rules!

"[`git sparse-checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d02343b5991d2dc24953fc0bda05f4c6fcde2781/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout))</sup> command learns a debugging aid for the sparse rule definitions.

See [commit 00408ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00408adeac13f6c16f93a3856961f7b327485c6b), [commit 24fc2cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24fc2cde6448233dbbe1f6695577a49679ccc98b) (27 Mar 2023) by [William Sprent (`williams-unity`)](https://github.com/williams-unity).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d02343b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d02343b5991d2dc24953fc0bda05f4c6fcde2781), 11 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/sparse-checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00408adeac13f6c16f93a3856961f7b327485c6b): add check-rules command
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: William Sprent</sup>

> There exists no direct way to interrogate git about which paths are matched by a given set of sparsity rules.
> It is possible to get this information from git, but it includes checking out the commit that contains the paths, applying the sparse checkout patterns and then using something like '[`git ls-files -t`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00408adeac13f6c16f93a3856961f7b327485c6b/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L140)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--t))</sup> to check if the skip worktree bit is set.
> This works in some case, but there are cases where it is awkward or infeasible to generate a checkout for this purpose.
>
> Exposing the pattern matching of sparse checkout enables more tooling to be built and avoids a situation where tools that want to reason about sparse checkouts start containing parallel implementation of the rules.
> To accommodate this, add a '`check-rules`' subcommand to the '`sparse-checkout`' builtin along the lines of the '[`git check-ignore`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00408adeac13f6c16f93a3856961f7b327485c6b/Documentation/git-check-ignore.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore))</sup> and '[`git check-attr`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00408adeac13f6c16f93a3856961f7b327485c6b/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr))</sup> commands.
> The new command accepts a list of paths on stdin and outputs just the ones the match the sparse checkout.
>
> To allow for use in a bare repository and to allow for interrogating about other patterns than the current ones, include a '`--rules-file`' option which allows the caller to explicitly pass sparse checkout rules in the format accepted by '`sparse-checkout set --stdin`'.
>
> To allow for reuse of the handling of input patterns for the '`--rules-file`' flag, modify '`add_patterns_from_input()`' to be able to read from a '`FILE`' instead of just stdin.
>
> To allow for reuse of the logic which decides whether or not rules should be interpreted as cone-mode patterns, split that part out of '`update_modes()`' such that can be called without modifying the config.
>
> An alternative could have been to create a new '`check-sparsity`' command.
> However, placing it under '`sparse-checkout`' allows for
>
> - a) more easily re-using the sparse checkout pattern matching and cone/non-code mode handling, and
> - b) keeps the documentation for the command next to the experimental warning and the cone-mode discussion.

`git sparse-checkout` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00408adeac13f6c16f93a3856961f7b327485c6b/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt#L12):

> `'git sparse-checkout' (init | list | set | add | reapply | disable | check-rules) [<options>]`

`git sparse-checkout` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00408adeac13f6c16f93a3856961f7b327485c6b/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt#L138-L160):

> ### `'check-rules'`
>
> Check whether sparsity rules match one or more paths.
>
> By default `check-rules` reads a list of paths from stdin and outputs only
> the ones that match the current sparsity rules. The input is expected to consist
> of one path per line, matching the output of `git ls-tree --name-only` including
> that pathnames that begin with a double quote (") are interpreted as C-style
> quoted strings.
>
> When called with the `--rules-file <file>` flag the input files are matched
> against the sparse checkout rules found in `<file>` instead of the current ones.
> The rules in the files are expected to be in the same form as accepted by `git sparse-checkout set --stdin` (in particular, they must be newline-delimited).
>
> By default, the rules passed to the `--rules-file` option are interpreted as
> cone mode directories. To pass non-cone mode patterns with `--rules-file`,
> combine the option with the `--no-cone` option.
>
> When called with the `-z` flag, the format of the paths input on stdin as well
> as the output paths are \0 terminated and not quoted. Note that this does not
> apply to the format of the rules passed with the `--rules-file` option.

Examples:

```bash
cat >rules <<-\EOF &&
    folder1
    deep/deeper1/deepest
    EOF
    git -C bare ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD >all-files &&
    git -C bare sparse-checkout check-rules --cone \
        --rules-file ../rules >check-rules-file <all-files &&
    git -C repo sparse-checkout set --cone --stdin <rules&&
    git -C repo ls-files -t >out &&
    sed -n "/^S /!s/^. //p" out >ls-files &&
    git -C repo sparse-checkout check-rules >check-rules-default <all-files
```