# A git deploy strategy that has different ignore rules for production?

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment

I have a project that is using git for source control. I also have a sass folder that I need to keep under version control, but I don't want that to get pushed to the production server.

I would like to be able to use "git push production" using a post-recieve git hook script as my deploy strategy.

Is there a way to have the production git deploy script ignore my /sass directory, so that it never makes it to production, but it's still safely under version control in my repo?

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer on StackOverflow that could help you, it uses `git archive` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495048/1706698

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain how this would fit into a deploy strategy? I would upload the archive that excludes the proper directories and extract it on my web server? Or is there a way to actually automate this like a git push to a production remote? Thanks!