# Git checkout removed local excluded files

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore

I have a project with several "test" files that I have included in my .git/info/exclude folder, to avoid pushing them.
As I wanted to keep this files backed-up in the git a well, I decided to put them into a new branch as follows:

```
git checkout -b newtestbranch
git add -f <path/to/test/folder/*>
git commit
git push --set-upstream origin newtestbranch
git checkout <mybranch>
```

After doing this, all the local files that I have forced-commited into the new branch were erased in my original branch (while they should stay there as they are in the exclude folder).

What have I done wrong? Is this an expected behavior?
I guess the issue is that these test files are in the working tree of the new branch but not the original branch, so they get deleted when doing the checkout. Is there a way to bypass this? I tried with [sparse-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933702/git-checkout-except-one-folder), but it does not work.

Note: I also have some untracked changes in the repository which I just stashed before doing this, and stashed pop afterwards.

Comment: I think you can employ a `post-checkout` hook that would test if the files are in the working tree. If not — the hook would restore them from a known good commit.

Comment: In this case of using the post-checkout hook, will the files be only restored locally, or will they start to appear in the git working tree of the original branch?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What is the difference between "locally" and "the git working tree of the original branch"? When you switch branches "locally" means "the git working tree of the current branch/commit", no?

Comment: It is because I do not want those files to be included in the original branch/commit. that is why they are included in the `.git/info/exclude` file, so that I have them "locally" in my PC but they are not included in the git working tree.

Comment: You've already committed them, so they're tracked. `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` are not applied to them; they only ignore not-tracked files.

Comment: I already committed them to the new branch, but not the original branch, so I was wondering if there is a workaround to checkout the original branch without those files being erased.

Comment: I don't think so. Git sees it's checking out from a commit where the files exist to a commit where they don't; it synchronizes the working tree by deleting the files that absent.

Answer (score 1):

You've already committed files to a new branch so Git sees them as tracked in that commit. `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` are not applied to them; they only ignore not-tracked files. When Git's checking out from a commit where the files exist to a commit where they don't it synchronizes the working tree by deleting the files that absent. I don't think there is a simple workaroud for that.

My advice is to create (or edit, if it exists) a `post-checkout` hook like this one:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# post-checkout hook: restore necessary files

if [ ! -f testfile ]; then
    git restore --source=master testfile
fi

exit 0
```

Put it in `.git/hooks/post-checkout`, make it executable, edit to your environment (put your file name and source commit; I use `testfile` and `master` as examples).

Warning — when you switch from a commit where the file doesn't exits to a commit where it exists and you edit the file comparing to what was committed — Git silently overwrite the file because it's listed in `.git/info/exclude` so Git ignores the file in the current commit (it's not tracked in this commit and is ignored).